# Weirdest thing: in python, if I don't use raw_input, lcd display gets text all scrambled

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Raspberry Pi and an LCD display 16x2 with Adafruit's module.
https://github.com/codecube/raspberry-pi-GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_CharLCD.py

```
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD

lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()
lcd.begin(16,1)
lcd.clear()
msg = "Message goes here"
lcd.message(str(msg))
```

This does not work. Text gets all scrambled, with some weird characters and it's totally erratic. If I run it a few times, I'll get something different every time. It could be something wrong with the LCD, the RPi or even with the soldering. But why is it fine when I do this:

```
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD

lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()
lcd.begin(16,1)
lcd.clear()
msg = raw_input("Enter message\n")
lcd.message(str(msg))
```

Perfect every single time. Everything I write is displayed perfectly this way. It can't be hardware, right? Is it the encoding? I have no clue.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? This may a problem with the way Python 2 displays strings.

Comment: @leaf Must be Python 2 because `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: @EliSadoff Was thinking. derp.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: I'm guessing the LCD driver wants a byte string, or something?

Comment: @cricket_007 But the OP says his second example using `raw_input()` works. `raw_input()` doesn't return a bytestring. Does it?

Comment: So one thing I noticed is that this isn't the official maintained driver in python. You can find that here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD

Comment: @leaf Unsure. A simple test shows `str(msg)` give the same string in both contexts. Same for `repr(msg)`

Comment: @CorvusCrypto Just tried that one too. Same thing.

Comment: also @cricket_007 and leaf I checked the source he uses... the bin() representation it ultimately uses is fine too... also there IS a delay in the write subroutine so the timing of waiting for raw_input vs. immediate string creation isn't the issue either. this is weird lol

Comment: @mnib since I don't want to read about the actual chip... does it fix it if you put a few thousand microsecond delay after declaring the string? I'm just throwing stuff at the wall and I'm sure their delays for clear() are fine... but this is again just a last-ditch sort of thought..

Comment: @CorvusCrypto Well, it seems we have a winner. Thanks. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @mnib glad it worked out. I'm gonna post an issue to this and a fix for them later on the main repo as well, but you should be able to fix this for now by adjusting the delay in L106 of the lib file you linked until it works consistently so you don't have to do a bunch of manual delays haha. Cheers!

Comment: @CorvusCrypto Just one more thing: if I adjust it to self.delayMicroseconds(100000), for instance, it doesn't work properly, but if I use sleep(0.1) instead, it works.

Comment: @mnib that's because in the lib you are using they do a division by int. So in python 2.7 100000/1000000 = 0 not 0.1.